# On a abelian representation of galois group

Tags: galois-representations

My question is quite elementary.

I am wondering all irreducible abelian Galois representation of $Gal(\bar{Q}/Q)$ should be character.(i.e 1-dimensional).

I think it should be ture. But since no guarantee on the compactness of abelian Galois group, I am hesitating to apply Schur Theorem.

How to show this?

Comment: Every Galois group is a profinite group, and hence compact; you needn't be worried on that count.

Comment: It might help to think of the Galois group as a projective limit of finite groups coming from finite Galois extensions, instead of some abstract group of automorphisms of an algebraically closed field.

Comment: For every locally compact abelian group the irreducible representations are one-dimensional. I am voting to close. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory

Comment: Dear all, thanks too much your reply. All comments are enlightening!